# install community engine on rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, communityengine

I have been trying for a to add the commmunity engine gem to an existing rails app following https://github.com/bborn/communityengine

1) I start with creating the app : rails new social

2) I Open gemfile, add gem 'community_engine', '~> 3.0.0' and set rails and sass-rails to gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0' and gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

3) I create a new application_config.rb and add configatron.community_name = "Social"

4) I delete gemfile.lock and run bundle install --binstubs. It says next to run bin/rake community_engine:install:migrations but I get the error

rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- aws/s3
/home/madmous/Desktop/social/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/madmous/Desktop/social/Rakefile:4:in`require'
/home/madmous/Desktop/social/Rakefile:4:in `'

I have been looking for the source of this error and I havent found anything to help.

I have been triny to also do git clone https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git but I do not know how to set up the application from a it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/issues/295

You either need to include `gem 'aws-s3'` in your Gemfile, or else use CommunityEngine from master (in Gemfile: `gem 'community_engine', :git => 'https://github.com/bborn/communityengine', :branch => 'master'`)

Comment: Thanks it helped me move forward with the installation. I am able to install migrations but I cannot migrate them. It says NoMethodError: undefined method `configure'

Comment: hey bborn, communityengine is awesome! Thanks for making it available. Could you possibly explain how I would go about using the actual source files from the master branch as a starting point to build my app? There is a large amount of customization I want to do and I've found that I am able to work much better when I have immediate access to the full directory. Currently I haven't even been able to run a a rails server from the root folder of the master branch as it does not seem to recognize it as a rails app.

Comment: @bborn Well I figured out why I couldn't get the server to run and added the a bin directory and the necesary config files, still getting errors, gona try and figure it out but let me know if you have any advice!